# HTACCESS Rewrite Error - Not working

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex in my .htaccess but it's not working. 
What I'm trying to achieve is for this link: `http://www.domain.com/` to receive 4 optional parameters, so it looks like this. http://www.domain.com/var1/var2/var3/var4.

But for some reason, this code does not work, I keep getting a 404 error.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^\.]+)/([^/]+)/([^\.]+)/$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks Helen.

**Update:**

If what I have above is not correct, could someone show me how I can supply 4 parameters to my url so `http://www.domain.com/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4` looks like this: `http://www.domain.com/var1/var2/var3/var4`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are three things we can say:

1. in the example you give in the intro there are no query arguments added, but tokens in a path. Yet in the `RewriteRule` you add query parameters. That does not match.
2. the 404 return code you get indicates that the file index.php does not exist (at least not where the server looks for it.
3. the regex you use inside the `RewriteRule` certainly won't match anything.

You should start by logging what is actually going on inside thr rewriting process. You won't udnerstand it otherwise. Check the two options `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` that mod_rewrite provides and their excellent documentation.

Comment: Thanks, will revise my code and see where I'm going wrong. This is my real attempt at using Regex in anger, believe it or not :)

Comment: Push aside your anger, it only keeps you from thinking :-) What I still don't understand from your question: what are those `vars` actually meant to be? Where should their value come from?

Comment: Thanks again- those vars are meant to do different things. Think of it as /people/gender/age/active. So, I basically run query based on those supplied vars. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, I begin to understand. You really should edit your question and correct the 'link' you mention which obviously is not `http://www.domain.com/` but `http://www.domain.com/people/gender/age/active`. And that you don't want to rewrite as said to `http://www.domain.com/var1/var2/var3/var4` but to `http://www.domain.com/index.php?var1=people&var2=gender&var3=age&var4=active`...

Comment: Ok, thanks for editing. Have you enabled loggin inside the rewrite module? It really will help to understand where the problem is! First I'd say you have to escape those "/" chars.

Comment: NO NO NO...you got me wrong. I want to rewrite it the other way. I need it to be this was `http://www.domain.com/people/gender/age/active`

Comment: You sure? That means there have to be files and folders called /people/gender/age/active if you rewrite _to_ that url. And no `index.php` script will ever be called. Direct question to get this clear: how does the http request look like that you receive from a client (browser)?

Comment: I've got it working like this: 
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4`. Thanks, will post if I run into another bump :)